# How do I select the “last child” of tr in my class should have no background styles

Tags: html, css

Here is the Working code, I just want to have the **last child for tr** should be clean without any css.

Here is my working [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/S5tB7/3/)

**Html**

```
<form id="frmAdmin" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Create Heading Details</legend>
        <table class="admin-table">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td>Title</td>
                <td><input id="Footer" name="Footer" type="text" value="">
            <tr>
                <td>Priority</td>
                <td><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Priority must be a number." id="Priority" name="Priority" type="text" value="">           
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Save">
```

**CSS**

```
form {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
fieldset {
    width: 79%;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.admin-table {
    width: 100%;
}
.admin-table td {
    background-color: grey;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
    height: 60px;
}
.admin-table  tr:last-child {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

**My output comes likes this:**
[image: My output comes likes this:]

**But my expected output is as like this image:**

[image: Image2]

Comment: How do you figure the last row is going to have no background color?  You haven't tried to override it or anything.

Comment: You should really fix your HTML markup closing every tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply the changes to `td`:

```
.admin-table  tr:last-child td {
    text-decoration: none;
    background:#ffffff;
    border:0;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S5tB7/10/)

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

```
.admin-table  tr:last-child td{
    background: none;
    border-color:transparent;
}
```

Check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/S5tB7/25/)

Answer (score 2):

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MbNz4/1/).

You need to apply the `background-color` change to the `td` elements of the last row -- since that is where you apply the yellow color in the first place.

```
.admin-table  tr:last-child td {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: initial;
    border:none;
}
```

Note that if you want the background color not just to be white, but to actually be "start" color, then set it to `initial` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial)).

Answer (score 2):

use below css

```
.admin-table tr:last-child td {
background: none;
}
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/S5tB7/3/

Answer (score 2):

```
 .admin-table  tr:last-child td
 { 
   background:none;
 }
```

Comment: but the background bottom line is visible.

Answer (score 0):

you didnt set up any background color

```
  body {background-color:white;}
  h1   {background-color:#00ff00;}
  p    {background-color:rgb(255,0,255);}
```